# Django: Loop through model names

Tags: django, for-loop

I want to loop through several models with my data generator function. Currently my page doesn't load and it just says This site can’t be reached. Anyone knows what I am doing wrong?

```
# Reset database
        models = ['ReservedItem', 'Ticket', 'Event', 'Organizer', 'User']
        for _model_name in models:
            **_model_name.objects.all().delete()
            print("Deleted ", model_name)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for the string mapping stuff you're trying to do, assuming your models are all imported into the file where you're doing this:

```
models = [ReservedItem, Ticket, Event, Organizer, User]
for m in models:
    m.objects.all().delete()
    print("Deleted {}".format(m._meta.label))
```

Comment: Awesome thank you. The problem for me were the ' 
So it was treated as a string. Thanks a lot!